# LINQ Performance

Tags: linq

What exactly is happening behind the scenes in a LINQ query against an object collection?  Is it just syntactical sugar or is there something else happening making it more of an efficient query?

Answer (score 12):

Do you mean in terms of a query expression, or what the query does behind the scenes?

Query expressions are expanded into "normal" C# first. For example:

```
var query = from x in source
            where x.Name == "Fred"
            select x.Age;
```

is translated to:

```
var query = source.Where(x => x.Name == "Fred")
                  .Select(x => x.Age);
```

The exact *meaning* of this depends on the type of `source` of course... in LINQ to Objects, it typically implements `IEnumerable<T>` and the `Enumerable` extension methods come into play... but it could be a different set of extension methods. (LINQ to SQL would use the `Queryable` extension methods, for example.)

Now, suppose we *are* using LINQ to Objects... after extension method expansion, the above code becomes:

```
var query = Enumerable.Select(Enumerable.Where(source, x => x.Name == "Fred"),
                              x => x.Age);
```

Next the implementations of `Select` and `Where` become important. Leaving out error checking, they're *something* like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                      Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (T element in source)
    {
        if (predicate(element))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
     Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        yield return selector(element);
    }
}
```

Next there's the expansion of iterator blocks into state machines, which I won't go into here but which I have an [article about](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx).

Finally, there's the conversion of lambda expressions into extra methods + appropriate delegate instance creation (or expression trees, depending on the signatures of the methods called).

So basically LINQ uses a *lot* of clever features of C#:

- Lambda expression conversions (into delegate instances and expression trees)
- Extension methods
- Type inference for generic methods
- Iterator blocks
- Often anonymous types (for use in projections)
- Often implicit typing for local variables
- Query expression translation

However, the individual operations are quite simple - they don't perform indexing etc. Joins and groupings are done using hash tables, but straightforward queries like "where" are just linear. Don't forget that LINQ to Objects usually just treats the data as a forward-only readable sequence - it can't do things like a binary search.

Normally I'd expect hand-written queries to be marginally faster than LINQ to Objects as there are fewer layers of abstraction, but they'll be less readable and the performance difference usually won't be significant.

As ever for performance questions: when in doubt, measure!

Comment: I meant what it does behind the scenes.  For example, i have an object collection.  I can write a For loop which iterates through the entire collection and just checks the property for the value I need in each object or I can use LINQ.  LINQ seems to be faster in many cases according to what I have read.  My question is why is it faster and how is it doing the lookups?

Comment: LINQ won't usually be faster than the equivalent code - although I believe there are other projects to provide indexed lookups, for example. If you could give a concrete example where you expect LINQ to be faster, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you need better performance, consider trying i4o - Index for Objects. It build in-memory objects for large collections (think 100,000+ rows), which LINQ then uses to speed up queries. You need a lot of data to make this work, but the improvements are impressive.

http://www.codeplex.com/i4o

Answer (score 2):

It's just syntactic sugar - there's no magic involved.

You could write out the equivalent code in "longhand", in C# or whatever, and it would perform the same.

(The compiler will do a good job of producing efficient code, of course, so the code it produces might be a fraction more efficient than the code you would write yourself, simply because you might not know the most performant way to write that code.)